# Do solid core doors reduce sound more than hollow-core doors?

Tags: doors, mdf, sound-deadening

I need to replace a bedroom door.  I would like to find the option that is best at dampening noise. I'm trying to decide between an MDF door like [Jeld-Wen Molded Composite MDF Interior Door Slab](https://www.homedepot.com/p/JELD-WEN-30-in-x-80-in-Colonist-Primed-Textured-Molded-Composite-MDF-Interior-Door-Slab-THDJW136501026/202036884)  or a solid core door like [Masonite solid core door](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Masonite-30-in-x-80-in-6-Panel-Right-Handed-Solid-Core-Textured-Primed-Composite-Single-Prehung-Interior-Door-38673/204638567).  Being that I'm mostly concerned with noise, which would be the best option.  Is there anything else I should consider when choosing, and am I overlooking a better option?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You'll want to [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how to participate here.

Comment: I’m surprised no one mentioned adding weatherstripping on the jambs, head, and threshold to reduce the transfer of sound. Most Weatherstripping has sound ratings.

Comment: a metal exterior door will block all but deep bass.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience solid core doors will block sound much better than hollow core. Solid core is also a heavier door which can be a plus although sometimes makes it a little more difficult to install.
Also, you want to make sure the door is pre-drilled for your hardware and pre-hung. The Jeld-Wen door you sited is a slab door and is not pre-hung. Slab doors need to have the hinges mortised and require more labor and knowledge to fit and hang correctly. So whichever type of door you go with (solid-core or hollow) make sure it's pre-hung.

Answer (score 2):

Looking over the product guides etc. for the JeldWen, it does not say if it is a solid or hollow core door, although its price say solid.

Never the less, when looking for sound deadening in doors, always go for density, in this case solid doors. And if both doors are solid, go for the heaviest one. That is if the difference is in pounds. Don't sweat it if the difference is only a couple of ounces.

Comment: I think it's hollow core because in the specs it limits how much of the door can be trimmed (1/4" on each side). That's usually typical of hollow-core.

Answer (score 2):

I recently replaced some hollow bi-fold doors that enclosed my air handler for my AC and heating unit. I got the heaviest, highest density, doors I could find. It's amazing how much the sound has been reduced. Definitely go with solid.